# CSS full width background images (negative margin) in Safari

Tags: css, safari, background-image, margin

I have a full width section in my WordPress page. It uses negative margins to create the full width (which works fine in Chrome, Safari, Edge and Firefox).

```
margin-left: calc(-100vw/2 + 100%/2);
margin-right: calc(-100vw/2 + 100%/2);
max-width: 100vw;
width: auto;
```

I added a background image via :before and :after to create some waves:

```
.waves:before {
content: '';
background-image: url(//lettering.tools/wp-content/themes/ostrichtheme/img/waves.svg);
background-position: center top;
background-size: 100% 70px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 70px;
position: absolute;
top: -1px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: -1;
}
```

It works fine in Firefox, Chrome, and Edge. But Safari does not want to view the background-image in full width and it looks really ugly on big screens. I tried different settings but can't get it work. Do you have any more ideas!? I don't want to remove that effect.

You can view a live example here: https://lettering.tools/
The full width section is directly after the first text block.

I used a combination of the answers to fix the problem.
But what if I don't want a responsive height of the SVG?

Also another problem occurred: An unwanted 1px line in Edge.
I tried negative bottom values and transform: translate. But it did not work.
Finally I realized the overflow: hidden on the container causes that 1px line - but why?!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you the following CSS (see comments in the code):

```
.no-sidebar .entry-content .alignfull
{
    margin: 0 calc(-50vw + 50%); /* simplify calculation, some browsers versions do not support division/multiplication */
    max-width: 100vw;
}

.waves:before, .waves:after /* you can combine selectors */
{
    content: '';
    background: url(//lettering.tools/wp-content/themes/ostrichtheme/img/waves.svg) 0 / cover; /* you can combine background properties */
    height: 5.83vw; /* you want it responsive, right? */
    position: absolute;    
    left: 0;
    right: 0;    
    z-index: -1;
}

.waves:before {top: -1px}
.waves:after {bottom: -1px; transform: rotate(180deg)}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I optimized the css and did it like Lumi said. Your way seems to work, too, but what if I want to keep the height at 70px? :-)

Comment: @Timo, if you keep 70px height, you loose waves aspect ratio. So it depends on your needs and preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Change `.waves:before` and `.waves:after` height to 100% and remove 70px in `background-size` so like this:

```
.waves:before {
    content: '';
    background-image: url(//lettering.tools/wp-content/themes/ostrichtheme/img/waves.svg);
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

then you will probably have the content inside further away from the waves so add more padding there

Like this:

```
.waves .wp-block-group__inner-container {
    padding: 90px 0;
}
```

Looks the same in both Safari and Chrome

Comment: Thank you! It works that way. But the height of the waves is changes with the browser width. Is there a way to keep the height at for example 70px?